# Wordpress Elementor - How to get rid of "Session padding" when adding an Image in it

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I am sorry the question must have been asked before but I could not find it
I am currently building my first site with Elementor and the Hello Theme

I would like to create a simple full-width section with two columns:
One image and one text

On the left I added an image and cannot get rid of the left margin (see picture)
I understood that the session's margin left-right is blocked and I would like to bypass it

I know there are others ways to achieve my goal like setting the image as the background of my column but I cannot believe one couldn't achieve this with a simple image

Thank you for helping me

[Section with left padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59qyM.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Set the column padding where the image is to 0, you hover on the section you will see the column icon on the top left of the column.